# Why PRINT affects @@rowcount

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rowcount

I recently noticed that while trying to loop through the rows of a table my loop wouldn't run based on if I had a `PRINT` statement before the the loop condition involving `@@ROWCOUNT`.

```
declare @s int;

select top 1 @s=sequence from myTable order by sequence;

while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    print @s
    select top 1 @s=sequence from myTable where sequence > @s order by sequence;
end

print @s
```

The above code prints what is expected; a sequence of numbers for each row in the table, but,

```
declare @s int;

select top 1 @s=sequence from myTable order by sequence;
print @s
while @@rowcount > 0
begin
    print @s
    select top 1 @s=sequence from myTable where sequence > @s order by sequence;
end

print @s
```

only prints the first value of sequence twice (one for each `PRINT` outside of the loop).

I tried reading up on the [PRINT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but found nothing on it affecting `@@ROWCOUNT`.

My question is, why does this `PRINT` affect `@@ROWCOUNT` and why isn't it more clearly documented because this can cause some bugs which are hard to debug?

**UPDATE**

After more research I did find

> Statements such as USE, SET , DEALLOCATE CURSOR, CLOSE CURSOR, PRINT, RAISERROR, BEGIN TRANSACTION, or COMMIT TRANSACTION reset the ROWCOUNT value to 0.

from [Microsoft's @@ROWCOUNT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` always refers to the previous executed statement, even `print`.

That is why code using `@@ROWCOUNT` almost always assigns the value to a variable:

```
declare @s int;
declare @rowcnt int;

select top 1 @s = sequence from myTable;
set @rowcnt = @@ROWCOUNT;

while @rowcnt> 0
    . . .
```